# How Can I Keep Some of My Application Files Outside of App Directory?

Tags: iphone, xcode

In my iPhone/iPad project, I'm showing some data from SQLite database. This database is under my `Supporting Files` folder in my Xcode project.

But my application also has a feature like "*bookmarking*" items. I intend to save "*bookmarked*" records by `ID` in a text file or whatever, then when user wants to see them, call the array in the text file and get the records from database.

But there's a possibility that my application might need update later. I've been researching about it and I think I should use a web service to check the current version and notify the user that there's a new version.

And also since the database is under my project folder, I expect the database to be modified too.

So far everything's all right, but what about my text file that I store user's *bookmarked* items' id's? Can I copy this outside of the folder so it doesn't get updated when user installs the new version of the application? Otherwise all the *bookmarked* values will be re-set.

Btw if there's any other effective version about releasing new versions and informing the user, I'm eager to hear. What I said is what I saw in related questions/answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you install an app update only the apps bundle is update, all will files sorted by the app aren't touched.

Comment: What about Sqlite database file? Where should I attach it to be modified?

Comment: If it is in the app bundle it will get replaced.

Comment: forgive me, but what is app bundle in Xcode 4 and what is NOT? I'm totally d(n)umb to this.

Comment: All files that are in the project (resources, image, databases) that you do not copy to the any directory are in the app [bundle](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFBundles/AboutBundles/AboutBundles.html).

Comment: How will the project know which file to include in installation file outside of bundle then?

Comment: It does not, the app bundle is de folder <aapname>.app, any any files that you create can't beplaced in this folder because it's readonly. Also there is no other way then via code to save files to the document directory (or any other directory outside of the app bundle).